# sql tally votes and return winner

Tags: sql

The objective is to return the image with the most stars(votes).  If there's a tie, its broken by the dateTime stamp; the first image to get the most votes.  There's 3 columns, imageName, stars, dateTime.  To populate this table, a user has cast a vote using a 5 star rating system.  Each image can have 1 to 5 stars, and multiple combinations of.  The statement needs to add up the total stars associated with each unique imageName, and then evaluate the dateTime stamp, if there's a tie. This is where I get lost.  There could be 4 occurrences of a unique imageName, each with 1-star for total of 5 votes.  Another imageName could occur once and have a single rating of 4-stars.

Sample table:

```
imagName ----- stars ----- DT
____________________________________________________
endeavourLiftOff.jpg ----- 1 ----- 2011-08-25 20:51:18
Image0016.jpg ------- ---- 1 ----- 2011-08-25 20:53:16
Image0016.jpg ------------ 3 ----- 2011-08-25 20:53:17
mantas_05-06.jpg --------- 4 ----- 2011-08-25 20:53:18
help.jpg ----------------- 3 ----- 2011-08-25 20:53:20
txHoldem.jpg ------------- 1 ----- 2011-08-25 20:53:21
Image0016.jpg  ----------- 1 ----- 2011-08-25 20:55:37
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Microsoft SQL

```
select top 1 xx.imagName
FROM
(
select imagName,min(dt),sum(stars)
from yourTable
group by imagName
ORDER BY 3 DESC,2 
) xx
```

Other dialects have other ways of getting the first occurrence

Comment: Fixed the query after seeing sample data, sorry

Comment: In MySQL you'd use LIMIT 1 instead of TOP 1

Answer (score 1):

You are getting lost on evaluating the time stamp, because your requirements are ambiguous.

Do you want to take the first timestamp, the last timestamp? The earliest vote overall as the tiebreaker?

I'm going to assume that you want to use the earliest-vote at the tiebreaker.

```
SELECT 
  A.*
FROM
  ( SELECT 
     I.imagName, 
     SUM(I.stars) as StarVotes,
     MIN(I.DT) as TieBreaker -- "Earliest Vote Tiebreaker"
    FROM 
      MyTable as I 
    GROUP BY I.imagName ) as A
ORDER BY
  A.StarVotes DESC, 
  A.TieBreaker
```

You may also care to use "average timestamp" as the tiebreaker, or "average timestamp per star" as the tiebreaker.